# achartengine bubble chart pan issue

Tags: android, achartengine

I am having a bubble chart in `achartengine`. I have a `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` and I have added a `XYValueSeries` and have plotted several points. I have custom labels for the X and Y axes. The problem is that the labels are so tiny when we display all of the points together. So what I did was I set `setXAxisMax(10)` and `setYAxisMax(10)` so that 10 points display at a time on the axes. But if you pan and move around the application crashes with the exception:

```
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=202; index=-51
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at org.achartengine.model.XYValueSeries.getValue(XYValueSeries.java:118)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at org.achartengine.chart.BubbleChart.drawSeries(BubbleChart.java:78)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.drawSeries(XYChart.java:540)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:320)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:181)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13944)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13825)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13823)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13823)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13823)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13823)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3083)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2920)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13947)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2224)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2482)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2395)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1872)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-20 09:56:11.427: E/AndroidRuntime(3041):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please let me know what could be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a issue with my own code. The X values need to be added incrementally to the XYValueSeries i.e if you add 5 then you cannot add a X value of 4 etc later. So I parse the JSON then sort the collection based on X value and then add them in that order to the series.